# Evenly spaced labels for polyline layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

I'm using QGIS 3.8 and am attempting to label roadway segments (OSM) of varying length. By checking the "Merge connected lines" box and hiding features below a certain size, I can generally limit the display of labels.

However, because of sharp turns in lines, or places where there are two parallel lines for the same segment, overlapping or doubling still occurs. Furthermore, in areas where all segments are under my specified size, there's no label at all.

[image: Too many labels]

I want to label all features, but no two labels of the same value (e.g. "35") should be within some distance of each other. Is that possible?